# How to filter array in object by few conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have such an object with newComments:

```
const newComments = {
  commentDirectoryId: "ee63997c-01d5-ec11-8dad-e116bd673e14",
  comments: [
    {
      id: "123",
      status: {
        entity: null,
        id: "1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f93",
        name: "In work",
        parentId: null,
      },
    },
    {
      id: "124",
      status: {
        entity: null,
        id: "1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f94",
        name: "Note",
        parentId: null,
      },
    },
    {
      id: "125",
      status: {
        entity: null,
        id: "1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f95",
        name: "Canceled",
        parentId: null,
      },
    },
    {
      id: "126",
      status: {
        entity: null,
        id: "1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f96",
        name: "Done",
        parentId: null,
      },
    },
  ],
  dataType: "Tags",
  idAttributeApprovalName: "12-015-123",
};
```

There are also filters:

```
const values = ["Note", "Canceled", "Done"];
```

My task is to return only comments that are not equal to keys:

```
comment.status.name !== "Note" | "Canceled" |"Done"
```

In other words:

```
const newComments = {
  commentDirectoryId: "ee63997c-01d5-ec11-8dad-e116bd673e14",
  comments: [
    {
      id: "123",
      status: {
        entity: null,
        id: "1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f93",
        name: "In work",
        parentId: null,
      },
    },
  ],
  dataType: "Tags",
  idAttributeApprovalName: "12-015-123",
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const newComments={commentDirectoryId:"ee63997c-01d5-ec11-8dad-e116bd673e14",comments:[{id:"123",status:{entity:null,id:"1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f93",name:"In work",parentId:null}},{id:"124",status:{entity:null,id:"1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f94",name:"Note",parentId:null}},{id:"125",status:{entity:null,id:"1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f95",name:"Canceled",parentId:null}},{id:"126",status:{entity:null,id:"1a913152-7809-ec11-8daa-90600b960f96",name:"Done",parentId:null}},],dataType:"Tags",idAttributeApprovalName:"12-015-123"};
const values = ["Note", "Canceled", "Done"];
newComments.comments = newComments.comments.filter(c => 
                        values.every(v => c.status.name !== v));
// or !values.includes(c.status.name) if no complex matching logic is required
console.log(newComments);
```